# Association rule mining using weka

Tags: weka, data-mining

I am trying to do association rule mining using weka tool

The length of record is not same for the data which I have.

```
Ex of the data:
a,b,c
a,b,c,d,e,f
a
k,g,y,r

In the above example
R1: length is 3
R2: length is 6 and so on
```

Because of different record lengths. weka is throwing error like

```
 wrong number of values read 3 expected 2.
```

Please let me know , How can I use Weka for association rule mining when 
the length of the record is not same?

Answer (score 0):

Use the *sparse arff* file format.

[ARFF format documentation](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/arff.html).

> ```
> {1 X, 3 Y, 4 "class A"}
> ```

see also the example .arff files.